# Cucumber reuse example

Tags: cucumber

I would like to use the Examples in the code below in the `"When I sign up with the following information"` line without having to specify every single parameter and without having to repeat the table in the examples.

Is this possible?

```
Scenario Outline: signing up a user that already exists
    Given I am registered as "<username>" with password "<password>"
    When I sign up with the following information
    Then I should be on the sign up page
    And I should see "user already registered"
    Examples:
       | email        |   username  | name        |   password    |  password_confirmation    |    city       |  mobile_numbers |
       | foo@bar.com  |   existent  | some user   | temp123       | temp123                   |     foobar    |  70 707070      |
```

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the cucumber project folder, the structure will contain a ruby file called env.rb within the support directory inside the features folder (along with the step_definitions folder). Here you can define your methods, variables, etc. that will serve as a common source for all your other tests inside the same project.

Since Cucumber is a Ruby gem, the data is defined in Ruby's format. You can define them as methods or variables. I prefer to define them as methods (in ruby, methods return their last line). So your methods will look like

```
    def email
        "foo@bar.com" # returns this when email is called
    end

    def username
        "existent"
    end
```

and so on...

You can optimize it to suit your needs. You will call them in your ste_definition files just like any normal ruby function would be called.

Comment: I might have not explained myself well... I wanted to reuse the table below Examples: in the line "When I sign up with the following information". I wanted to see if this is possible without having to do something like: "When I sign up with the following information: "<username>","<password>", "<city>", "<mobile_numbers>" ...

Comment: In this case, you would want to create a method in Ruby in env.rb which will have all those values inside it and you will call that function in your step_definition file. So it will be something like
  
    def login
        # - create variables here
        # - perform actions
    end
Now, you can just call login method and it will do everything for you. The sample project in GitHub has a very basic example of this.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm unable to format for the code in the comments